# How do I make a boolean attribute go back to a default value in a Python class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, attributes

I'm trying to make a class to handle logic Literals and I want to account for negated literals by overloading the `__neg__()` operator:

```
class Literal():

def __init__(self,n):
    self.name = n
    self.sign = True

def __neg__(self):
    self.sign = False
    return self

def __repr__(self):
    return self.name
```

Nothing too complicated; what I have now successfully changes the `sign` attribute to `False` when I define an instance `A=Literal('A')` and run the command `(-A).sign`. However, if I later run `A.sign` the attribute is still set to `False`, which I don't want. I want the value of `A.sign` to always return `True` and the value of `(-A).sign` to always return `False`.

Note: I can't just make a secondary instance `other` and set `other.sign = False` because regardless of its `sign` value, any call to `A` should reference to `A` and not a copy.

I've been playing around with different ideas such as setting a `@property` but can't seem to figure it out so I turn to the internet for help. Thanks in advance and let me know if you would like any more info!

EDIT:

I made it return a new instance as I had previously done since it seems everyone agrees that's the best option. I added an example case of the problem this generates so it's more clear:

```
class Literal():

def __init__(self,n,s=True):
    self.name = n
    self.sign = s

def __neg__(self):
    result = Literal(self.name, not self.sign)
    return result

def __repr__(self):
    return self.name

A = Literal('A')
B = Literal('B')
C = Literal('C')

print((-A).sign)
>>> False
print(B.sign)
>>> True
print((-B).sign)
>>> False
print(A.sign)
>>> True
print(B.sign)
>>> False
```

That works. However, I need to gather a list of the literals in a list of sets (this is representing CNF) later, and having the separate instances causes a problem because I end up with duplicate literals:

```
test = [{A,-B},{B,C},{-A,C}]
lits = []


for x in test:
    for i in x:
        print(x,i,i.sign)
        if i not in lits:
            lits.append(i)

print(f'\n{test}')
print(lits)

>>> {B, A} B False
>>> {B, A} A True
>>> {B, C} B True
>>> {B, C} C True
>>> {C, A} C True
>>> {C, A} A False

>>> test: [{B, A}, {B, C}, {C, A}]
>>> lits: [B, A, B, C, A]
```

Literals `B` and `A`, which were negated, are duplicated because of this implementation of the `sign`.

Hope this clarified my previous note.

Comment: Shouldn't `__neg__` return a *new* instance, with `sign` set to `False`?

Comment: "Note: I can't just make a secondary instance other and set other.sign = False because regardless of its sign value, any call to A should reference to A and not a copy." But `A` will still reference the original `A`, unless you manually *re-assign* the new object to `A`.... Try it out.

Comment: I would, but that's what I clarified I can't do since this would leave me with basically two same-name instances of different values. I can see scenarios where that's not a problem but I need there to be just one instance with any same name. If I did what you suggest (which I tried already) I eventually end up with two `A` Literals that have different sign values, which is not what I want.

Comment: In that case you can't use `__neg__`. I suppose there is a reason why you don't want to use `not A.sign`? Could this be an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)?

Comment: It very well could be an XY problem, hence me posting here to get others' perspectives. I added in the edit the description of why I don't want to use a new instance, like I said in OP, I've been trying different ideas for a bit but can't seem to figure it out so I'm open to any ideas on how to reframe it.

Comment: To mitigate the problem with multiple instances, you could simply check if the name is in list, not the object itself. `if i.name not in lits: lits.append(i.name)`

Comment: Fair point, that might work... I'll need to change the way I call a few things later on but I think you're actually onto a pretty neat solution to this annoying problem...

Comment: Actually, just realized I can overload `def __eq__(self,o): return self.name==o.name` and voilà...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to change the original you have to create a new instance.

```
class Literal():
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.name = n
        self.sign = True

    def __neg__(self):
        result = Literal(self.name)
        result.sign = False
        return result

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

a = Literal('A')
print((-a).sign)
print(a.sign)
```

But there's a problem with your code. You always return `False` for the sign. This means that `(-a).sign` and `(--a).sign` are the same. You should change `__neg__` to the following code.

```
    def __neg__(self):
        result = Literal(self.name)
        result.sign = not result.sign
        return result
```

If you add the sign as an optional parameter to `__init__` the code could look like this.

```
class Literal():
    def __init__(self, n, sign=True):
        self.name = n
        self.sign = sign

    def __neg__(self):
        return Literal(self.name, not self.sign)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name
```

For maximum flexibility you can replace `return Literal(self.name, not self.sign)` by `return self.__class__(self.name, not self.sign)`.

Comment: Thanks for the `not self.sign` tip that's useful even though I won't be assigning double negations. I guess I didn't express myself very well though, because I already tried returning a new instance but the issue with this is I end up with basically two instances of the same name but different values of `sign` and really what I need is the same instance to have a different attribute depending on the operator.

Comment: I overlooked that part. At the moment I'm thinking about creating kind of a proxy wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

@jonrsharpe is correct: `__neg__` should return a new instance:

```
class Literal():

    def __init__(self,n, sign=True):
        self.name = n
        self.sign = sign

    def __neg__(self):
        return Literal(self.name, sign=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name


a = Literal('a')
print((-a).sign)
>>> False
print((a).sign)
>>> True
a = -a
print((a).sign)
>>> False
```